# Matlab failed to open m file

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and I've installed it successfully. Everything works fine. But when ever I try to open `.m` files, I always get following error popping out of dialog box:

```
Error using open(line 162)
Failed to open matlab editor.
```

And in command window it throws a lot of Java exceptions.

First of all please forgive my poor English. 
I've been searching for this problem all over the internet but couldn't find any useful solution.

I'm using `windows 8.1 pro 64-bit` os.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that there is an error in a line that justs consists of

`<br>`

This is not valid matlab code (looks more like html). As such it seems like you have either messed up the `open` function, or overloaded it somehow.

I think the first thing to do is check `which open` and see where this points you.

If this does not help, try to look at the matlab path carefully and see whether you accidentally added a (html?) file on it called `open.m`.

Lastly, you could try to use the built in open function directly, check `doc builtin` for this. If you succeed at least you are sure it is not a matter of corrupting the standard file.

Comment: I'm afraid sir, but that <br> tag was added by me. Because i am new to this website and have used it for few times only. Try to read by omitting <br> tag. There is a dialog box that says the above two message. Sir, I am glad you've replied to my answer but i couldn't find any solution please help me.. Thank you

Comment: @user3213732 In that case, please have a look at [this thread on matlabcentral](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/300659). If that does not work, please try the steps that I mentioned and describe what happens.